# DTO/VO and Presentation Model

Tags: apache-flex

In Flex world, is DTO / VO same as Presentation Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not. Presentation model is used to move state and logic out of a view into another class, where it can be developed and unit tested more easily.

VO/DTO represent domain objects that are exchanged between the client and the server

Comment: Hi Florian,  Thanks for the response.  I understood the difference now.  Your answer and Brian's article on PM clarified my doubts.  Once again thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Florian is right.  I did a write-up of what "Presentation Model" is here, if you are curious to know what the PM pattern is:

http://riarockstars.com/2011/03/16/presentation-model-and-multiple-screens-part-1/

Comment: Hi Brian, Your article on Presentation Model was fantastic.  It explained the concept in simple words.  Thanks a lot for sharing it. Now I am very clear about VO/DTO and PM.  Thank you!!!